# Entity Framework HasPrecision is not validated on save

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, decimal, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6, Code first approach

When setting the precision of a property using the `HasPrecision` method in an `EntityTypeConfiguration` class, it seems only to affect the truncate behavior of the decimal value. Is there any way to force Entity Framework to throw an error in case the precision is not as specified (same as `MaxLength` does if the string length is too long).

Example:

`this.Property(t => t.Amount).HasColumnName("Amount").IsRequired().HasPrecision(19, 2);`

When setting Amount to `5.4567` and saving the entity, the value being saved is `5.45`

I would prefer to get an error in such a case.

What would be the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think a way could be to create your validation logic using 
`DbContext.ValidateEntity` method

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.validateentity%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, there's no such way. That's how non-integer numbers work in a computer. Decimal numbers in a computer are generally not exact, and they only get exact by rounding.

Such is that, that if you do:

```
Console.WriteLine((0.1 + 0.2).ToString("R"));
```

The output will be `0.30000000000000004` (the `R` there is so it can show the 17 digits that `double` stores, instead of the 15 it shows by default on a `ToString()`). You can [check it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4Lnfc).

You only get 0.3 as a result if you actually round it, but the internal storage is not exact, and it's only an approximation of 0.3 (so approximate that if you round to any significant amount of digits -any less than 17 decimal positions in this case-, you'll get 0.3).

This is not arbitrary, it's defined in the IEEE 754 standard ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_formats)).

So there's just no way (except for some carefully chosen numbers) you could get to store exactly-rounded-to n-th precision numbers in a computer and it'd be throwing constantly.

You could validate your entries if you want to throw, but I just can't think of a scenario in which doing that is practical.

If you go the way of validating, please notice that:

```
 Console.WriteLine((0.1+0.2)==0.3);
```

Returns `False` (for precision issues), so be wary of HOW you validate your entries to be rounded

Comment: What about the magnitude? They should at least validate that 12345.0 is too large to fit into a decimal(6,2)?